# Working Holiday Visa In France

Tags: visas, france

I'm having a hard time finding information about this online. I'm Canadian and I want to apply for a working holiday visa in France. They say that you can only apply up to three months in advance. I want to travel Asia for 4-5 months before arriving in France.

If I apply in June and ask for my visa to start in September but I actually end up arriving in France in November. Will they refuse my entry? Or will my visa only be valid for 10 months instead of the original year because I got there two months late?

Also, if anyone has any personal experience about how long it took them to receive an answer once they went through the application/ interview process, that would be great.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote here. A working holiday visa is edge case for both [travel.se] and [expatriates.se]. The fact that this question is _really_ about applying for a w.h. visa _during an existing walk-about_ kind of makes it more our edge than Expats... IMHO

Comment: Did I post this incorrectly? I've never used this forum before. Let me know if I need to change something in order to get an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Vanessa questions about long-term relocation are supposed to go in http://expatriates.stackexchange.com.  There are often questions that could arguably belong in either place.  Since your plans to apply for the visa are complicated by travel plans, there is a "travel" angle even though the working holiday visa itself is probably better suited to "expatriates."  If you post this to expats, however, I doubt there will be anyone suggesting it should move to travel, so you might be better off posting it there.

Comment: I think this is fine here.